# USB drive messed up - permissions error? Input/output error on copy, ls, mv

Tags: usb, permissions, filesystem

I've tried fsck, e2fsck, dosfsck to fix this USB, putting files manually working fine, editing appears to work? cd to the directory works - but read/write is absolutely fubared. I've tried fsck -a to auto fix, etc.

Output:

```
user@notme:~/Downloads/lslife/rmrfusb$ ls -la /media/user/
total 12
drwxr-x---+ 3 root   root        4096 Oct 18 10:06 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root        4096 Oct  3 08:08 ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 user   domainusers 4096 Oct 18 10:07 New Volume

user@notme:~/Downloads/lslife/rmrfusb$ ls -la /media/user/New\ Volume/test/
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 1 user   domainusers    0 Oct 18 10:00 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 user   domainusers 4096 Oct 18 10:07 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 user   domainusers 4096 Oct 18 10:00 coursedocs

user@notme:~/Downloads/lslife/rmrfusb$ ls -la 
/media/user/New\ Volume/test/coursedocs/
ls: reading directory '/media/user/New 
Volume/test/coursedocs/': Input/output error
total 0
```

If I elevate to root, I still experience the same error, log:

```
root@notme:~# ls -la /media/user/New\ 
Volume/test/coursedocs/
ls: reading directory '/media/user/New 
Volume/test/coursedocs/': Input/output error
total 0
```

df -Th output:

```
/dev/sdb2      fuseblk    60G  369M   60G   1% /media/user/New Volume
```

**The solutions I've seen previously don't help, I'm just trying to re-take ownership over this directory, and root won't allow me to**

Comment: I/O errors probably mean a hardware defect.

Comment: It's odd, because I can read/write every other file and folder with ease.

Comment: Maybe you could try backing up all data from the drive somewhere and zeroing it out (overwriting the whole device with zero-bytes). After that, if it didn't encounter any errors, you should be able to format it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input / output error, drives randomly refusing to read / write](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15476/input-output-error-drives-randomly-refusing-to-read-write)

Comment: @ByteCommander Saw that one, but it's not a working solution for this. The disk status is fine, it's just this directory that I need to take ownership over somehow-root won't allow me to do that.